# update and insert in mongodb import

Tags: mongodb

The following command is correctly importing the data from csv file. But the problem is that there are 2 entries for the same number.
I need both the entries for 417176718 in the same document (so no $set). How do I keep both these values using mongo import?

```
cat final.txt
number, date, duration, type, destination
417176718 , 2013-01-23 20:09:00 , 1 , NORMAL_CLEARING , 61998487
409334392 , 2013-01-24 11:25:18 , 40 , NO_ANSWER , 09821973636
919480909 , 2013-01-25 20:58:00 , 40 , NORMAL_CLEARING , 09919480909
417176718 , 2013-01-24 20:09:00 , 1 , FAILED , 61998487

mongoimport -d mydb -c vcalls --type csv --file final.txt --headerline
```

Comment: I think you will have to write your own script to do this. MongoImport will not do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what a map reduce is for.

Once you've got this in the db, run a map reduce like this:

```
mapper= function(){emit(this.number, {'data':[{'date':this.date, 'duration':this.duration, 'type':this.type, 'destination':this.destination}]});}

reducer = function(k,v){
    data=[];
    for (i=0;i<v.length;i++){
          for (j=0;j<v[i].data.length;j++){
                data.push(v[i].data[j]);
         }
    }
    return {'data':data}
}
db.vcalls.mapReduce(mapper, reducer, 'reducedcalls')
```

This should give you data that a single record per number with a list that contains the calls.

Comment: Great. I had to use out: { inline: 1 } because of some version issue. If I have millions of such records, will it work?

Comment: If you want millions, you'll want them in a new collection. Try {out:'newcollection'}

Comment: I get an exception: Converting from JavaScript to BSON failed: Object size 17037962 exceeds limit of 16793600 bytes # How do I pass this exception, as I do not need such large documents but need all others.

Comment: Amazon m3.xlarge instance processed around 22 million records in around 45 minutes. Interesting!